# Need batch file that will call the server name from text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need batch file that will call the server name in the listed text file and run he command on the same.

eg.

**Script.bat**

```
xcopy c:\Tool\DiskCleanp.bat \\%ServerName%\C$\Tool\ /Z /Y >> C:\result.txt
Psexec \\%ServerName% c:\tool\DiskCleanp.bat C:\result.txt
```

**Server.txt**

```
Server01
Server02
Server03
Server04
```

Or Is there is any tool that will created a automatic batch file as per the requirement.

Thanks in advance ...Accept as Solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the /F option on the FOR command. Run 
help for
for more information.

Something like (untested!):

```
for /F %%i in (server.txt) do (
   xcopy c:\Tool\DiskCleanp.bat \\%%i\C$\Tool\ /Z /Y >> C:\result.txt
   Psexec \\%%i c:\tool\DiskCleanp.bat C:\result.txt
)
```

Note that both the brackets around the file name and the brackets around the block of commands are round brackets / parentheses.